# Replicating Cathode retro terminal effect?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to replicate the effect of [Cathode](http://www.secretgeometry.com/apps/cathode/) but i'm not really aware of any rendering effects in SDL. Does anyone know the technique used in Cathode? Are they using OpenGL and shaders maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are still interested in the subject I'm working on a similar project. The effects were obtained by using GLSL shaders. 
You can grab the source code here: https://github.com/Swordifish90/cool-old-term/

The shaders strings might not be extremely readable due to the extensive use of the ternary operators (needed to customize the appearance) but they should give you a really good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you poke around a bit in the application bundle, you'll find that the only relevant framework is GLKit which, according to Apple, will "reduce the effort required to create new shader-based apps".

There's also a bunch of ".fragdata", ".vertdata", and ".glsldata" files, which are encrypted.
Very unfortunate for you.

So I would say: Yes, it's OpenGL shaders all the way.

Unfortunately, since the shaders are encrypted, you're going to have to locate suitable algorithms elsewhere.
(Perhaps it's possible to use the OpenGL debugging and profiling tools to capture the shader source as it is compiled, but I doubt it.)

Answer (score 1):

You may have realized that Android phones have (had?) such animations when you put them to sleep. That code is available under in file named [ElectronBeam.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/power/ElectronBeam.java).

However it is Java code and uses GLES 1.0 with GLES 1.1 Extenstions but algorithm for bending screen should be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be based on GLTerminal which uses OpenGL, it would have to use OpenGL and shaders for speed.

I guess the fastest approximation would be to render the text to buffers within OpenGL and use a deformed 2d grid to create the "rounded corners" radial distortion.

But it would take a lot of work to add all the features that cathode has, not to mention to run them quickly.

I suspect emulating a CRT perfectly is a bit like emulating an analog synth perfectly - hard to impossible.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to work quickly and not killing the CPU, the GPU is the best solution! So pixel shaders. pixel shaders can do all of these effects. Once I made such an application. I wrote it in Silverlight, but it does not matter, I used the pixel shader.
Suggests to write this in Qt4 and add to the QWidget pixel shader effects.